# Uniform integrability of a certain sequence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space, and let $\{g_{n}\}$ converge in $L^{1}(\mu)$ (or even merely in the weak topology) to $g$. Suppose that $f:X\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function such that $fg_{n}\in L^{1}(\mu)$ for all $n$, and $\sup_{n}\int_{X}\vert{fg_{n}}\vert d\mu<\infty$. Is it true that $\{fg_{n}\}$ converges in $L^{1}$? It is obvious (follows from Komlos's lemma and Fatou's lemma) that $fg\in L^{1}(\mu)$.

I am not sure how to go from here. One previous approach I used which seems to not work is the following argument: since $\sup_{n}\int_{X}\vert{fg_{n}}\vert d\mu<\infty$, $\{fg_{n}\}$ is equicontinuous as a sequence of linear functions $L^{\infty}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$, and then trying to deduce weak convergence (which implies uniform integrability by Dunford-Pettis) on a weak-star dense subset of $L^{\infty}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\frac 1 x$ on $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure and $g_n(x)=n1_{(\frac 1 {2n}, \frac 1 {2n-1})}$. Then, $\int |g_n| \to 0$. Also, $\int fg_n=n[\ln (2n)-\ln (2n-1)]=n\ln {(1+\frac 1 {2n-1})}\to \frac 1 2$.
If $fg_n$ converges in $L^{1}$ then it can only converge to $0$ since $g_n \to 0$ in $L^{1}$. [Use  a subsequence argument].  We have arrived at a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks! I'm surprised that this statement is false.

Answer (score 0):

Once you know about the sufficient condition for uniform integrability $\sup_n E|X_n|^{1+\delta}<\infty$ for some $\delta>0$ (and thus $L^1$ convergence), the answer is obviously no. Indeed, let $g_n = n\mathbf 1_{(0,1/n)}$. Thus $g_n \to 0$. On the other hand, $\int g_n \equiv 1$.

Comment: This is not a counterexample, as gn are assumed to converge in L1